# MYSQL - You can't specify target table 'packs' for update in FROM clause

Tags: php, mysql, select, union

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE packs set `LastmovementTypeID`=9 WHERE `ShipmentID` IN (SELECT ShipmentID FROM packs packs2 WHERE (packs2.TaskMarker = '2' AND packs2.Movementtype != 'Bezorgscan depot' AND packs2.LastmovementTypeID != 0) UNION SELECT ShipmentID FROM packs packs3 WHERE (packs3.TaskMarker = '3' AND packs3.LastmovementTypeID != 0))
```

and when i execute it i get the result

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'packs' for update in FROM clause
```

what is the reason to this? because what i want to update are the records from the same table where my ShipmentID is not found in the list returned by the query:

```
SELECT ShipmentID FROM packs packs2 WHERE (packs2.TaskMarker = '2' AND packs2.Movementtype != 'Bezorgscan depot' AND packs2.LastmovementTypeID != 0) UNION SELECT ShipmentID FROM packs packs3 WHERE (packs3.TaskMarker = '3' AND packs3.LastmovementTypeID != 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get round this constraint with something like this:

```
UPDATE packs set `LastmovementTypeID` = 9 
WHERE `ShipmentID` IN 
    (SELECT ShipmentID FROM 
        (SELECT ShipmentID FROM packs packs2 
            WHERE (packs2.TaskMarker = '2' AND packs2.Movementtype != 'Bezorgscan depot' AND packs2.LastmovementTypeID != 0) UNION SELECT ShipmentID FROM packs packs3 WHERE (packs3.TaskMarker = '3' AND packs3.LastmovementTypeID != 0)
        ) AS `x`
     );
```

Comment: THANKS a million :D that did the job just awesome :D I owe you one ;)

Answer (score 3):

As it says in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html: "Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery."

You need to design a work-around - select into a temp table, for example, and then update from there.